# CSS - Two Divs overlapping, both with fixed width

Tags: html, css

So after several attempts i'm a little lost right now.
I have a two columns layout.

html:

```
...
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Both (left and right) have a fixed width, for example 700px. What i want them to do is, when the viewport width is smaller than 1400px the right div should overlay the left div. I successfully did it with position: absolute on the left div and float right on the right div. But this does work only as long as the height of the right div is bigger than the left div.

If requested i can add an image. Any help or hint would be awesome. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

i have to support ie8+. and both divs should be visible. i added an image, hope it makes my requirements more clear.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I created a jsbin to show what i'm trying to achieve. Right now it is the position absolute solution, but as i said it isn't working when the content of the position absolute div is bigger than the other floated div (see jsbin). you have to start the jsbin output in a extra tab. Then reduce the window width to see the desired effect.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vudomowilo/4/edit)

Comment: "right div should overlay the left div" so we only see right div  ?

Comment: `position:absolute; left:0; z-index:1;` on left div, `position:absolute; right:0; z-index:2;` on right div?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional css :

```
<html>
<style>
#left{
    width:700px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
#right{
    width:700px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) { 
    #left{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
    }
    #right{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:5;
    }
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">a</div>
  <div id="right">a</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have edit my answer, left and right still display now. Less efficient i think

Comment: unfortunately i can't use media queries because of the ie8 support.

Comment: Responsive without media query is impossible, so you have to use javascript to check page width an apply class

Answer (score 0):

Your overlay definistion is a bit rough,

maybe you mean this?

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1400px; 
}

#left, #right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px; //or whatever
    overflow: auto;
}

#left {
    background-color: black;
    left: 0;
}

#right  {
    background-color: grey;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

EDIT: Added a fixed height with scrolling.

Comment: i've updated my question. but as i said position absolute isn't working in my case because of the dynamic height if each div (left and right).

Comment: You can either set a defined height and scroll if its too high, Or you have to use javascript I fear.